# Is there a way for a scraping script to pause for the user to manually log into a website and then resume with scraping the site?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Here is what I have so far:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/uglyr/chromedriver')  
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com')

#now the script must pause until I manually login.

...

#after successful login the script must resume taking me from my feed page to my profile page

profile = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-control-name='identity_profile_photo']/parent::a")

profile.click()

sleep(4)
# the code to scrape my own profile
```

I am building a webapp and I would like to give the users the ability to import their profile in the webapp after they logged in their LinkedIn account.

After **scraping** the profile information I would display it for the user to confirm and import this info to the app's database. Most probably I will need to run the webdriver remotely, but will cross that bridge when I get to it.

I would appreciate any ideas you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `wait.until` function. You can read more about it here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver')  
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login?')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ember227"]')))

profile = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div/div/div/aside[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a')

profile.click()

sleep(4)
```

Comment: thanx for the answer, I tried this but I get a timeout exception in like 2 seconds. The driver does not wait for 10 secs so there is no time for me to manually login.

Comment: strange, i'm getting a timeout after 10 secs! Can you post your error here? is it really timeout? Have you tried to increase the time until timeout?

Comment: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f6cdad1c81d3> in <module>
     10 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
     11 
---> 12 wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ember227"]')))
     13 
     14 profile = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div/div/div/aside[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a')`

Comment: `~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message: `

this is the error message I get

Comment: did you try to increase the value from `10` to maybe `30`?

Comment: I just did. And when I increase it to `30` instead of `10` it gives me enough time to log in. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You could wait for your own feedback with prompt like this:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/uglyr/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com')

#now the script must pause until I manually login.
while True:
    # print("Did you login yet?")
    answer = input("Did you login yet?")
    if answer == 'Yes':
        break
...

#after successful login the script must resume taking me from my feed page to my profile page

profile = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-control-name='identity_profile_photo']/parent::a")

profile.click()

sleep(4)
# the code to scrape my own profile
```